# Parenthesis folding in Eclipse PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, editor, pydev, word-wrap

Is there any way to customize Eclipse PyDev line folding? When a function call gets a lot of arguments, I prefer to fold my code like this:

```
def some_function():
    function_call(
        first_argument=first_value,
        second_argument=second_value,
        third_argument=third_value,
        ...
    )
```

However with PyDev this is really hard. Hitting RETURN after `function_call(` will bring me to next line with the identation finishing on same column as `(`. It looks like this:

```
def some_function():
    function_call(
                  # My caret lands here.
```

Not a big issue, but couldn't find anything in the settings nor on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under window > preferences > pydev > editor > typing, uncheck the "after '(' indents to its level (indents by tabs if unchecked)".

Comment: I overlooked this one somehow. Thank you very much!